# reduce the group action

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations, group-actions

I would like to understand the following statement:

```
The usual way to study the action of a group is to construct a continuous section of the
action.
```

Take a group $G$ acting on a topological set $S$.
A continuous section of the action $\mathcal{A} : G\times S \rightarrow S$ is a section of the projection $p:S \rightarrow S/G$ (continuous for the topology on $S$).

$S/G$ is the set all of orbits of $S$ under the action of $G$ which form a partition of $X$.

So if I construct a section $s:S/G \rightarrow S$ such that $p\circ  s=id_{S/G}$, how to relate to the study of the action $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself "what is $S/G$ telling me in terms of the action?" That is, first assume that $G$ acts transitively on $S,$ and then what should $S/G$ look like? Then try to get a more general picture.

Comment: Ok so in that case S/G=S. The projection p is the identity and so is s. I have difficulty to see that if we have identity section then the action is transitive.

Comment: If $G$ acts transitively on $S,$ then for any $s\in S,$ we have $Gs=S,$ where $Gs$ is the orbit of $s,$ and so $S/G$ is a singleton . . .

Comment: indeed thanks,
so s maps the only orbit ${\hat x}$ to the whole set $S$.  With a single orbit we can reconstruct the set S and we recover the transitive property of the action A.

Comment: So what are the sections of the map $p:S\longrightarrow S/G$?

Comment: The sections are all the maps : $s: \hat x \rightarrow x $ where x is any element of S?